# Работа с геометрическими векторами

Tags: c#

Подскажите, существует ли в C# встроенный класс для работы с геометрическими векторами или, возможно, хорошую библиотеку, предоставляющую данный функционал?

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.mathdotnet.com/
- http://www.alglib.net/download.php

Ну еще с кодепрожекта http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/AdvancedMatrixLibrary.aspx